# If Else sendo ignorado

Tags: python, tkinter, automatização

Estou iniciando agora em programação... Rodei o debugger e notei que o `if/else` (# TKINTER RESULTS GRID) está sendo ignorado, finalizando o codigo sem erro algum no console. Testei algumas modificações mas não obtive sucesso.

O que poderia estar causando o problema?

```
    try:
        if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/span').is_displayed():

            # DROPDOWN CLICK TO MAKE ITEMS VISIBLE
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/span').click()

            time.sleep(1)

            dropd = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/main[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/ul/li')
            print(len(dropd))

            i = 0

            for item in dropd:
                time.sleep(1)

                print(item.text)
                benef = item.text

                item.click()


                # CLIENT CODE HAVE NOTIFICATION
                if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notification"]').is_displayed():
                    ....

                # CLIENT CODE DOESN'T HAVE NOTIFICATION
                else:
                    ....

                # TKINTER RESULTS GRID
                if age < 75:
                    idade_plc = Label(frame_idade, text=age, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
                    idade_plc.grid(row=i + 3, column=0, sticky=EW)
                elif age > 75:
                    idade_plc = Label(frame_idade, text=age, borderwidth=1, relief="groove", bg='red')
                    idade_plc.grid(row=i + 3, column=0, sticky=EW)

                benef_plc = Label(frame_benef, text=beneficio, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
                ...

                if qnt >= 9:
                    qnt_plc = Label(frame_qnt, text=qnt, borderwidth=1, relief="groove", bg='red')
                    qnt_plc.grid(row=i + 3, column=0, sticky=EW)
                elif qnt < 9:
                    qnt_plc = Label(frame_qnt, text=qnt, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
                    qnt_plc.grid(row=i + 3, column=0, sticky=EW)

                ...

                i += 1

                time.sleep(2)
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/span').click()

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Onde estaria essa variável "age"? Porque pela analise da logica de programação, o if/else so não rodaria se age fosse 75

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] da sua tentativa de solução. Para entender e aproveitar melhor o site vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).